# How to create a union type of an object and a primitive type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a "small" problem finding the correct typing in Typescript. What is the problem?

I have a variable `selected` which can be either of type `DistanceSplit` or `number`. In my code I'm dealing with a list like this:

`[-100, DistanceSplit, DistanceSplit, DistanceSplit, -100]`

I have no problems when `selected` is of type `any`. But now I'm trying to eliminate all `any` from my code (also for a better readability). Unfortunately, this causes now in some compilation errors.

Typically, `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'DistanceSplit'.` or `selected.name is not assigned to type number` etc.

Well, I understand why this error occurs, but the question is: how can I solve it with Typescript?

```
export const TRANSPONDER_Distance = -100;

export interface DistanceSplit {
    ID: number;
    name:string;
    content:string
}

// working
public selected: any;

// not working
public selected: DistanceSplit | number;


function() {
    this.selected.name = "bla";  // problem
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `selected` variable is typed correctly. Although you still have to check wether your selection is either a `number` or a `DistanceSplit` in your function.

You can tell TypeScript that `selected` is of type `DistanceSplit` before setting the `name` property by using a `Type Guard`.

---

In your case it would be good enough to do it this way:

```js
function() {
  if (typeof this.selected !== 'number') {
    this.selected.name = 'foo';
  }
}
```

This will tell TypeScript that if it isn't a number, it must be a `DistanceSplit`.

---

If you need anything more specific, you can write a type guard function like this:

```js
function isDistanceSplit(selected: number | DistanceSplit): selected is DistanceSplit {
  // Some logic that will make sure that selected is of type DistanceSplit.
  return (typeof selected !== 'number');
}
```

You can now define your example like this:

```js
function() {
  if (isDistanceSplit(this.selected)) {
    this.selected.name = 'foo';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle the typings a union type, you have to some point handle when it is a number and when it is a DistanceSplit type.

To do that, you can simply force the typings like this:

```js
function() {
    (this.selected as DistanceSplit).name = "bla";
}
```

If you need more information, have a look at https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types